# Como verificar o valor de varias switchs no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, switch

Olá, eu estou criando um aplicativo de checklist, porém a checklist tem mais de 30 itens e estou usando "Switch".
Quando o usuário preencher tudo ela vai mandar para uma database onde outra pessoa irá ver os itens que estão "checkados", porém queria saber um jeito de verificar todas as switchs sem ter que verificar uma por uma por exemplo:

"extensoData" é o mês que foi feito a check list

```
item = findViewById(R.id.checklist_item1);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CheckList").child(extensoData.toString()).setValue(item.isChecked()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(CheckListsem.this, "CheckList feita.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Como tá a hierarquia do seu database?

Comment: ```CheckListID -> Veiculo-> Data -> item1 = "true"````

obs; "Veiculo" seria o nome da checklist que a pessoa esta fazendo, por ex; tem 2 tipos de checklist "Trator" e "Kombi".

Comment: Não consegui enxergar muito bem ainda, mas não daria pra vc salvar todos os itens checados ao invés de um boolean pra cada, mas salvar como um Array de strings? Assim vc recupera de uma vez só tudo o que havia sido checkado.